# What details should be hidden in the Data Access Layer?

Tags: c#, .net, data-access-layer

I'm creating a *Data Access Layer* (DAL) to read/modify some tables stored in an XML file. While my application is running, the rows of these tables are updated very often, therefore I thinking about two possible alternatives:

1. When the application starts, I could load all the data in tables through the DAL and put them in a data structure such as a `Dictionary`. While the application is running, this dictionary is continuously updated. When the application is closing, I invoke a method of the DAL in order to overwrite the old file with the new data in the dictionary.
2. It would probably be more correct to hide this dictionary to the upper layers, so I might have a `Dictionary` private field in the DAL. In this way, the upper layers would call the methods of the DAL to update the rows of the tables.

Is perhaps the second approach better than the first one?

Comment: Do readers always need to have the most updated values?  Or can they have an "eventually consistent" view of the files?  Also, do the writers lock the files properly to prevent reading half-written data?

Comment: Is this a winforms app?  Will the XML data be stored on a server somewhere with multiple copies of the app accessing it simultaneously?

Comment: @ChrisShain: The only reader is the app itself, which is multi-thread, so different threads could read/write at the same time the tables (and the XML file). The threads (ie the readers) need to have the most updated values.

Comment: @ChrisLively: This is a WPF app. A single copy of the XML file is stored locally in the app folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 2 here is better for encapsulation though does increase complexity.  The dictionary is an implementation detail that your upper levels shouldn't be concerned with.  Instead your data access layer should expose classes that represent the actual tables - for example you may have a `Person` class or an `Inventory` class.  As DAL classes these would provide methods for adding, deleting, updating, retrieving etc. as appropriate.

Further up you'd have a domain layer which operates on a row retrieved from your DAL classes that would add business methods (e.g. an `Order` could be made by a `Person` and impacts `Inventory` - the act of invoking methods on these domain classes goes down to the DAL to actually touch the underlying data).

Comment: In this way all updates would update the dictionary in the DAL, then the DAL may periodically update the XML file and not after each row update.